# SQL Server long term backup policy

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, powershell, python

I wish to implement a long term backup policy in SQL Server on VM, much like Retention policies in azure sql database.
I have full backup once a week, diff once a day and log backup every 15 minutes.
I wish to keep all backup files for PITR for 30 days.
Than keep every last full backup of each month as a monthly backup for 12 months and one full backup, the last one in a year, as a yearly backup.
The backup is done to a blob storage on Azure.
Any idea how to start?
Point me to a python example perhaps or anything that can get me started will be much appreciated .
Thanks

Comment: I recommend SQL Backup Master, which can do all of this for you

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not have that capability inherently like Azure SQL does. Azure SQL accomplishes this by the platform outside of Azure SQL doing that for you. For you to accomplish this, you have to have jobs run in SQL Agent or another scheduler that takes backups on the intervals you want. Then based on those intervals, move the backup files to a long term storage area. That could be inside your data center or maybe back to an Azure storage account. Python is not a requirement for this as you can do this natively with T-SQL.

Take a look at the [Ola Hallengren backup scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html). They are the gold standard for DBAs looking to manage their backups. There is an example for backing up databases to local storage and to an Azure Blog storage account. The Ola Hallengren scripts will also have parameters for cleanup. So in one job you can keep things around for 30 days, but in another job, you can delete the files after 12 months.

Comment: It looks like ola script does not support Azure storage cleanup: "cleanup is not supported on Azure Blob Storage"